# Link fails when cross compiling OpenCV 3.3.1 for Raspberry Pi Zero even though libraries are present

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, opencv3.0

I've been attempting to build OpenCV 3.3.1 for the Raspberry PI Zero (Raspbian stretch) on Ubuntu 16.04. I've been following the steps documented here https://github.com/HesselM/rpicross_notes with the major exception that instead of using the tools from https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools which have GCC 4.9.3 I used crosstool-ng to build a GCC 6.3.0 toolchain to match the GCC version shipped with Raspbian stretch. I've installed all the OpenCV prerequisites on a RaspberryPi Zero and then taken a copy of the filesystem to use as the system root.

CMake configuration appears to work but the make build fails when linking `libopencv_freetype.so` as the harfbuzz and freetype libraries are not found.

```
/opt/cross/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/6.3.0/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreetype
/opt/cross/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/6.3.0/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/freetype/CMakeFiles/opencv_freetype.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_freetype.so.3.3.1' failed
```

These libraries are present in my RaspberryPI system in usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 dsnowdon dsnowdon 717178 Apr 27  2017 libfreetype.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 dsnowdon dsnowdon    909 Apr 27  2017 libfreetype.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dsnowdon dsnowdon     21 Apr 27  2017 libfreetype.so -> libfreetype.so.6.12.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dsnowdon dsnowdon     21 Apr 27  2017 libfreetype.so.6 -> libfreetype.so.6.12.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 dsnowdon dsnowdon 567844 Apr 27  2017 libfreetype.so.6.12.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 dsnowdon dsnowdon 739360 Jan 24  2017 libharfbuzz.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dsnowdon dsnowdon     24 Jan 24  2017 libharfbuzz.so -> libharfbuzz.so.0.10400.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dsnowdon dsnowdon     24 Jan 24  2017 libharfbuzz.so.0 -> libharfbuzz.so.0.10400.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 dsnowdon dsnowdon 551256 Jan 24  2017 libharfbuzz.so.0.10400.2
```

Building with make VERBOSE=1 shows that the failure occurs when this command is run:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/opencv_freetype.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
```

Which generates this:

```
/opt/cross/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -fPIC   -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG  -shared -Wl,-soname,libopencv_freetype.so.3.3 -o ../../lib/libopencv_freetype.so.3.3.1 CMakeFiles/opencv_freetype.dir/src/freetype.cpp.o ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.3.1 -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt ../../3rdparty/lib/libtegra_hal.a -lfreetype -lharfbuzz ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3.1
```

However if I manually add `-L${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` to give the following then the link works:

```
/opt/cross/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -fPIC   -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG  -shared -Wl,-soname,libopencv_freetype.so.3.3 -o ../../lib/libopencv_freetype.so.3.3.1 CMakeFiles/opencv_freetype.dir/src/freetype.cpp.o ../../lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.3.1 -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt ../../3rdparty/lib/libtegra_hal.a -lfreetype -lharfbuzz ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.3.3.1
```

This led me to think that maybe pkg-config was being called in such a way it was not emitting the correct libdir so I wrote a wrapper script to dump all the pkg-config invocations and results.

```
#! /bin/bash
LOGFILE=/tmp/pkg-config-wrapper.log
basename="`basename "$0"`"  
timestamp=$(date)
printf "${timestamp} ${basename} $@\nPKG_CONFIG_DIR=${PKG_CONFIG_DIR}\nPKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=${PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR}\nPKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=${PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR}\n"  >> $LOGFILE
result=$(/usr/bin/pkg-config "$@")
printf "pkf-config = ${result}\n"  >> $LOGFILE
echo $result
```

This is what I found for harfbuzz related to linking (I've omitted the other invocations of pkg-config cflags, for freetype and gtk for brevity):

```
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:54 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --exists
--print-errors --short-errors harfbuzz
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = 
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:54 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --modversion
harfbuzz  
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = 1.4.2
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:54 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --variable=prefix
harfbuzz  
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = /usr

Wed  8 Aug 06:33:54 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --variable=libdir
harfbuzz  
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:54 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --libs-only-l
harfbuzz  
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = -lharfbuzz
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:55 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --static
--libs-only-l harfbuzz 
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = -lharfbuzz -lglib-2.0 -lpcre -lgraphite2
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:55 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --libs-only-L
harfbuzz  
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = -L/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:55 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --static
--libs-only-L harfbuzz 
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = -L/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:55 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --libs
harfbuzz  
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = -L/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lharfbuzz
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:55 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --static
--libs harfbuzz 
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = -L/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lharfbuzz -lglib-2.0 -pthread -lpcre -pthread -lgraphite2
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:55 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --libs-only-other
harfbuzz  
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = 
Wed  8 Aug 06:33:55 BST 2018 pkg-config-wrapper.sh --static
--libs-only-other harfbuzz 
PKG_CONFIG_DIR=
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/share/pkgconfig:/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs
pkg-config = -pthread
```

As far as I can see pkg-config is being invoked correctly for cross-compilation so now I'm at a loss and am not sure what to try next.

I'm invoking CMake as follows:

```
cmake \
-D RPI_ROOTFS=${RPI_ROOTFS} \
-D BUILD_TESTS=NO \
-D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=NO \
-D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=${RPI_CROSS_HOME}/src/opencv_contrib-3.3.1/modules \
-D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${RPI_CROSS_HOME}/src/opencv-3.3.1/platforms/linux/arm.toolchain.cmake \
${RPI_CROSS_HOME}/src/opencv-3.3.1
```

Most of the changes to the OpenCV Cmake files are in `opencv-3.3.1/cmake/OpenCVMinDepVersions.cmake` as described in https://github.com/HesselM/rpicross_notes

```
set(MIN_VER_CMAKE 2.8.12.2)
set(MIN_VER_CUDA 6.5)
set(MIN_VER_PYTHON2 2.6)
set(MIN_VER_PYTHON3 3.2)
set(MIN_VER_ZLIB 1.2.3)
set(MIN_VER_GTK 2.18.0)

# install dir
set( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/local CACHE STRING "")
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${RPI_ROOTFS}" CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER )

# compilers
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER   "/opt/cross/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"    CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/opt/cross/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-g++"    CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( CMAKE_AR           "/opt/cross/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-ar"     CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( CMAKE_RANLIB       "/opt/cross/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib" CACHE FILEPATH "")

#Pkg-config settings
set( RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR "${RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR}:${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig" )
set( RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR "${RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR}:${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/share/pkgconfig" )
set( RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR "${RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR}:${RPI_ROOTFS}/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig" )

#set( PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/pkg-config" CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "/opt/cross/pkg-config-wrapper.sh" CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( ENV{PKG_CONFIG_DIR}         "" CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR}      "${RPI_PKGCONFIG_LIBDIR}" CACHE FILEPATH "")
set( ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} "${RPI_ROOTFS}" CACHE FILEPATH "")

# setup rpi (target) directories for compiler
set( RPI_INCLUDE_DIR "${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR} -isystem ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf")
set( RPI_INCLUDE_DIR "${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR} -isystem ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/include")
set( RPI_INCLUDE_DIR "${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR} -isystem ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/local/include")

set( RPI_LIBRARY_DIR "${RPI_LIBRARY_DIR} -Wl,-rpath ${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf")
set( RPI_LIBRARY_DIR "${RPI_LIBRARY_DIR} -Wl,-rpath ${RPI_ROOTFS}/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf")

# Setup C/CXX flags.
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS        "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS          "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${RPI_INCLUDE_DIR}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${RPI_LIBRARY_DIR}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

#Python2.7
set( PYTHON_EXECUTABLE          /usr/bin/python2.7 CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON_LIBRARY_DEBUG       "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE     "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON_LIBRARY             "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR         "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/include/python2.7" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include" CACHE STRING "")
set( PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH      "${RPI_ROOTFS}/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" CACHE STRING "")
```

I also changed `opencv-3.3.1/platforms/linux/arm.toolchain.cmake` according to https://github.com/HesselM/rpicross_notes replacing "-mthumb" with "-marm" to give this

```
if(COMMAND toolchain_save_config)
  return() # prevent recursive call
endif()

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR)
  set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
else()
  #message("CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
endif()

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/gnu.toolchain.cmake")

if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL arm AND NOT ARM_IGNORE_FP)
  set(FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX "")
  if(NOT SOFTFP)
set(FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX "hf")
  endif()
endif()

if(NOT "x${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION}" STREQUAL "x")
  set(__GCC_VER_SUFFIX "-${GCC_COMPILER_VERSION}")
endif()

if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_C_COMPILER)
  find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER NAMES ${GNU_MACHINE}${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-gcc${__GCC_VER_SUFFIX})
else()
  #message(WARNING "CMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} is defined")
endif()
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER)
  find_program(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER NAMES ${GNU_MACHINE}${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-g++${__GCC_VER_SUFFIX})
else()
  #message(WARNING "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} is defined")
endif()
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_LINKER)
  find_program(CMAKE_LINKER NAMES ${GNU_MACHINE}${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-ld${__GCC_VER_SUFFIX} ${GNU_MACHINE}${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-ld)
else()
  #message(WARNING "CMAKE_LINKER=${CMAKE_LINKER} is defined")
endif()
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_AR)
  find_program(CMAKE_AR NAMES ${GNU_MACHINE}${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-ar${__GCC_VER_SUFFIX} ${GNU_MACHINE}${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX}-ar)
else()
  #message(WARNING "CMAKE_AR=${CMAKE_AR} is defined")
endif()

if(NOT DEFINED ARM_LINUX_SYSROOT AND DEFINED GNU_MACHINE)
  set(ARM_LINUX_SYSROOT /usr/${GNU_MACHINE}${FLOAT_ABI_SUFFIX})
endif()

if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS           "" CACHE INTERAL "")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS             "" CACHE INTERAL "")
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "" CACHE INTERAL "")
  set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "" CACHE INTERAL "")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "" CACHE INTERAL "")

  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS           "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi")
  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS             "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi")
  if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL arm)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS           "-marm ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS             "-marm ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc")
  endif()
  if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL arm)
set(ARM_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now")
  elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL aarch64)
set(ARM_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now")
  endif()
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${ARM_LINKER_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
  set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${ARM_LINKER_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "${ARM_LINKER_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
else()
  #message(WARNING "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}' is defined")
endif()

if(USE_NEON)
  message(WARNING "You use obsolete variable USE_NEON to enable NEON instruction set. Use -DENABLE_NEON=ON instead." )
  set(ENABLE_NEON TRUE)
elseif(USE_VFPV3)
  message(WARNING "You use obsolete variable USE_VFPV3 to enable VFPV3 instruction set. Use -DENABLE_VFPV3=ON instead." )
  set(ENABLE_VFPV3 TRUE)
endif()

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH} ${ARM_LINUX_SYSROOT})

if(EXISTS ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR})
  set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH} ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR})
endif()

set(TOOLCHAIN_CONFIG_VARS ${TOOLCHAIN_CONFIG_VARS}
ARM_LINUX_SYSROOT
ENABLE_NEON
ENABLE_VFPV3
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR
)
toolchain_save_config()
```

This is the CMake output:

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.3.1 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/src/opencv_contrib-3.3.1/modules
--     Version control (extra):     unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2018-08-08T05:33:57Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64
--     Target:                      Linux 1 arm
--     CMake:                       3.5.1
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:
--       requested:                 DETECT
--       disabled:                  VFPV3 NEON
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++11:                       YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /opt/cross/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-g++  (ver 6.3.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /opt/cross/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include  -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include  -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/include -isystem /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/include   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml objdetect phase_unwrapping photo plot reg surface_matching video xphoto bgsegm dnn face freetype fuzzy img_hash imgcodecs shape videoio xobjdetect highgui superres bioinspired dpm features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo structured_light tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow stitching python2
--     Disabled:                    js world contrib_world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python3 ts viz cnn_3dobj cvv dnn_modern hdf matlab sfm
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 3.x:                    YES (ver 3.22.11)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.50.3)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        zlib (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg (ver 90)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.24)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
--     GDCM:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.64.101)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 57.56.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 55.34.101)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.2.100)
--       avresample:                YES (ver )
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver )
--       video:                     YES (ver )
--       app:                       YES (ver )
--       riff:                      YES (ver )
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver )
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     Intel Media SDK:             NO
--     gPhoto2:                     YES
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES ()
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use Intel IPP:               NO
--     Use Intel IPP IW:            NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Lapack:                  NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use OpenVX:                  NO
--     Use custom HAL:              YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
--     Include path:                /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/src/opencv-3.3.1/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
--     Libraries:                   /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.13)
--     numpy:                       /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver undefined - cannot be probed because of the cross-compilation)
--     packages path:               /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /opt/software/packages/java/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin/ant (ver 1.9.6)
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       NO
--     Performance tests:           NO
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/rootfs/usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/build/opencv
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /opt/software/raspberrypi/rpi-cross/build/opencv
```

At this point I'm at a loss and don't know what to try next. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I run up exactly to the same problem. For me the solution was to copy `libfreetype.a` and `libharfbuzz.a` to the directory `/home/alfred/Development/raspi-tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/`.

This is the sub directory from where the compiler and linker are started (64bit because my ubuntu is a 64bit system).

I think this is just a dirty workaround, but I don't know how to fix with cmake system. Please let me know if you have found a better solution.

Comment: I'll give it a go but I have tried a build with freetype disabled (-DBUILD_opencv_freetype=OFF) and that just failed later when it failed to pick up the include directory for gstreamer. The issue I'm having looks to be not freetype specific, just that freetype was the first library the build hit that depended on an external library.

Comment: I think the compiler and linker setup points to the wrong header and lib files. With my workaround I had a linking error. I have to directories:<br/>

- `~/Development/raspi_rootfs` ... clone from rapis
- `~/Development/raspi-tools`

Comment: Then I made a symbolic link from the build system to the raspi clone:
`~/Development/raspi-tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc -> /home/alfred/Development/raspi_rootfs`. This worked for me. I compiled a few test programs on ubuntu18 64bit and run it successfully on raspi. Old `libc` has been moved to a backup.